# What is the meaning of this sentence "We got on the bus downtown"

Tags: differences

**Which one is correct?**

1. We were going downtown by the bus.
2. We got on the bus when we were there (downtown).

Comment: For definition 1 i think people would say "We got the bus downtown" (no on), or "We got on the downtown bus.".  Therefore, most likely to be 2 i think.  But it's a guess, I don't think there is enough information to do anything other than guess.

Comment: You can say - We went downtown by bus. But : We got on the bus downtown - we took the bus from the center of town. We got on the downtown bus - we took the bus going downtown.

Comment: "We got on the bus downtown," means we went downtown and got on the bus. "We got on the downtown bus," means we stepped onto the the bus which would take us downtown, also "We got the downtown bus," means we caught the bus which was heading downtown.

Comment: Max, I saw this sentence in a grammar book, "Basic Grammar in Use, Cambridge University Press", I think it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illogical as it seems, ***"We got on the bus downtown"*** often means:

***"We got on the bus*** *(that goes)* **downtown."**

For example - if we start with the premise that a conversation is taking place regarding a concert in Central Park, (uptown, NYC) the conversation may go as follows:

**"How did you get to the concert?"**

***"We got on the bus downtown."*** (We were downtown, and we got on a bus that travels uptown.)

**"How did you get home from the concert?"**

***"We got on the bus downtown."*** (We got on a bus that was heading downtown.)

*The answer is:* ***it all depends on context.*** (AmE)